# python visa is very slow

Tags: python, visa, windows-10-desktop

Python 3 `pyvisa` slowed down after `Windows 10` update. My program has been working ok before and now after some win updates it's very slow.

Actually It didn't work at all before I re-installed `NI-VISA`.

Simple example with debug info shows the time. Some kind of timeout?

```
import visa;
visa.log_to_screen();
rm=visa.ResourceManager()
2016-09-14 19:50:27,600 - pyvisa - DEBUG - No user defined library files
2016-09-14 19:50:27,605 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Automatically found library files: ['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\visa32.dll', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\visa32.dll']
2016-09-14 19:50:27,607 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Library signatures: 90 ok, 0 failed
2016-09-14 19:50:27,607 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Created library wrapper for C:\WINDOWS\system32\visa32.dll
rm.list_resources()
2016-09-14 19:54:27,746 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viOpenDefaultRM('<ViObject object at 0x00000000054A0748>',) -> 0
2016-09-14 19:54:27,746 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Created ResourceManager with session 4097
2016-09-14 19:54:27,994 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viFindRsrc(4097, '?*::INSTR', '<ViObject object at 0x00000000054A0748>', 'c_ulong(1)', <ctypes.c_char_Array_256 object at 0x00000000054A0CC8>) -> 0
('USB0::0x0957::0x2007::MY49002886::INSTR',)
2016-09-14 19:54:27,994 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viClose(<ViObject object at 0x00000000054A0748>,) -> 0
```

Comment: What exactly is slow? Resource listing? Or communication with an instrument?

Comment: I cannot remember any more how it was at the time. However, I suppose communication was very slow (like you see there is 4 min before resource manager is created).